# Haml: how do I set a dynamic class value?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following html.erb code that I'm looking to move to Haml:

```
<span class="<%= item.dashboardstatus.cssclass %>" ><%= item.dashboardstatus.status %></span>
```

What it does is associate the CSS class of the currently assigned status to the span.

How is this done in Haml? I'm sure I'm missing something really simple.

Comment: was your solution the same as below?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure. Maybe:

```
%span{:class => item.dashboardstatus.cssclass }= item.dashboardstatus.status
```

Comment: how do you do it when your tag is not a direct html tag, but generated through a rails helper?

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple conditional class selectors with array syntax:

> %div{ class: [ ("active" if @thing.active?), ("highlight" if @thing.important?) ] }

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

Where ever the link is to the page do something like this

```
  %div{"data-turbolinks" => "false"}
    = link_to 'Send payment', new_payments_manager_path(sender_id: current_user.id, receiver_id: @collaboration.with(current_user).id, collaboration_id: params[:id]), class: 'button'
```